# how to test custom directive with jasmine?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I made a custom directive in my app and now want to unit test it with karma and jasmine but my test fails. 
Here is my directive:

```
<div my-data remoteurl='url' filter='test' order-by='sortExpression' order='order'></div>
```

myappcontroller:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myAppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.url = 'https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json';
        $scope.filter= 'test';
        $scope.orderBy= 'sortExpression';
        $scope.order= 'orderBy';
    }])
    .directive('myData', ['$http', function($http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope: {
                remoteurl: '=',
                filter: '=',
                orderBy: '=',
                order: '='
                // orderBy:'sortExpression':'order' ;
            },
            templateUrl: 'DataTable.html',
            link: function(scope, element, attr) {

                $http.get(scope.remoteurl).success(function(response) {
                    scope.names = response.data.children;
                });
            }
        };
    }]);
})();
```

When I run this, I will get this error:

```
       C:\wamp\www\First-angular-App>karma start karma.conf
        INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.16 server started at        http://localhost:9876/
       INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
       INFO [Chrome 44.0.2403 (Windows 8)]: Connected on socket    TEd9Xo5aEr_WPAJCbfjc wi
      th id 79057650
      Chrome 44.0.2403 (Windows 8) unit testing directive order style should be false
     in the beginning FAILED
      Error: Unexpected request: GET DataTable.html
      No more request expected
         at $httpBackend (C:/wamp/www/First-angular-   App/bower_components/angu
      lar-mocks/angular-mocks.js:1178:9)
```

How can I do this ? Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated as I have gotten stuck here, so guide me. I am new to angular.

Comment: @Shohel can you  guide me?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
var views = [
    'DataTable.html'
];
views.forEach( function( view ) {
    beforeEach( module( view ) );
} );
```

and

```
httpBackend.expectGET( 'https://www.reddit.com/r/worldnews/new.json' ).respond( 200 );
```